# How to realize Path Variable in retrofit 2

Tags: android, request, retrofit2

I can't send DELETE request with path variable. It's working in [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ6jM.png). Please help me.

**UPD:**

API Interface: `@HTTP(method = "DELETE", path = "users/id:{id}", hasBody = true) fun deleteUser(@Path("id") id: String): Call<ResponseBody>`

Comment: please provide more data of how you are implementing it

Comment: @OmidKzm edited.

Comment: ` error 404`  - Can you check in logs if you are calling the correct url.  [Error 404](https://www.lifewire.com/404-not-found-error-explained-2622936) basically means api/page not found on server

Comment: Its working `DELETE https://61c0b1a****23581.mockapi.io/news/users/2` in Postman. But retrofit is not working. (sorry about my English)

Comment: When calling  from retrofit , does it form the same url as of postman? Check url formed by app in the logcat at the time of calling the api

Comment: @Nitish urls are same

Comment: Worked: `@HTTP(path = "users/2", method = "DELETE")
    fun deleteUser(): Call<User>`  Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using retrofit 2. Try like this

```
@DELETE("delete_labour/{id}")
Call<JsonElement> delete_item(@Path("id")String id,
                                @Header("token")String token);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet below

```kotlin
@DELETE("users/{id}")
fun deleteUser(@Path("id") id: String): Call<ResponseBody>
```

Comment: unfortunately it didnt work

Comment: returned error 404

Comment: I have already done like that and it worked